# UnsatisfiedLinkError when crawling in Nutch

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, nutch

Am trying to setup Nutch and facing this issue when crawling for the first time.

**Command used**

```
$ bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://localhost:8080/solr/ urls/ TestCrawl /2
```

**Errors obtained**

[image]

**Setup info**

- Nutch 1.3
- Java JRE v1.8u131
- Windows Server 2012 R2 (Actually tried on Windows 10 too. Same error obtained)

**Solutions tried**

- Adding 'winutils.exe' and 'hadoop.dll' into 'bin' folder of Apache Nutch
- Set environment variables 'JAVA_HOME', 'NUTCH_JAVA_HOME' to point to the Apache Nutch folder
- Set environment variable 'HADOOP_HOME' to point to Apache Nutch folder (as 'bin' will be the folder where the hadoop dlls be stored
- Add value to System 'Path', i.e. '{Apache Nutch folder}\bin'

Appreciate if anyone can tell me what I can do to fix. Thanks.

Comment: first try for single URL, and check your url formate, i think it should start with http:// OR https:// (may be must)